# Why are hash table based data structures not the default when implementing adjacency lists?

Tags: language-agnostic, graph-theory

I looked at some existing implementations of adjacency lists online, and most if not all of them have been implemented using dynamic arrays. But wouldn't hashtable based data structures be more suitable? (set and map)

There are very limited scenarios where we would access graph nodes by index. Even if that's the case, if some indices are missing from the graph, there will be wasted space. And if the nodes are not inserted in order, lookups are O(n).

However, if we use a hashtable based data structure, lookups will be O(1) whether the nodes are indexed or otherwise.

So why are maps and sets not the default data structures used when implementing adjacency lists?

Comment: A look-up in a hash-table has O(1) in best case (and O(N) in worst case even if this should be unlikely). A look-up in an associated array has O(lg(N)) in worst case. A look-up in an array (by index) has O(1) in worst case. (Of course, if look-up in arrays by index is not possible this can become worse.) Furthermore, arrays (with consecutive storage) are cache friendly. If you are free to chose the identifiers of nodes, then there is nothing which can beat an array with index. (You still have the option to introduce an internal ID if there is none in the data the graph is loaded from.)

Comment: I'll add that map probably  can't even represent adjacency lists in a good way. Consider this - each element at least must a pointer to two other elements, besides some data to distinguish it from other elements. I would also disagree about arrays with index - linked lists are not an indexed arrays really because again each element has at least two! pointers to other elements - and the term `next` is not really appliable in this case

Comment: Btw. just recently I had a look at the design of the Boost Graph Library. In the BGL, the storage type of node lists and edge lists is configurable, and they spent an extra page to explain what should be cared about concerning this: [BGL adjacency_list](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_77_0/libs/graph/doc/adjacency_list.html). (In fact, vectors aka. dynamic arrays seem to be the defaults there.) ;-)

Comment: @Scheff'sCat Thank you very much for your reply. I understand what you are stating. Would you be kind enough to offer some advice on the example below. Imagine we are building a graph where each node is a town with a name as id. According to your answer, I can create consecutive integer ids for each town and store them in either an associative map(O(logn)) or a hash map(averageO(1)). When I need to look-up the graph, I first look-up the id table, get the id, and then look-up the graph using that id. Am I correct? Or is there a more efficient implementation available? Thank you.

Comment: If a town is given, you have in fact to look-up the corresponding internal ID - once. But, in your algorithms (e.g. to find a route from A to B) you may have many look-ups to follow edges from one node to the other. Now, the indexed access with O(1) will surely pay off. - I even dare to say that for the mapping of town names to IDs, you may use any container as it will be used only to pre-process user input (e.g. a request for a certain start or destination town). So, even O(N) won't probably hurt so much. (Users are slow anyway - compared to the CPUs.)

Comment: @Scheff'sCat I completely understand now. Thank you for your help :)

Comment: _for the mapping of town names to IDs, you may use any container_ i.e. you can use an associated array or hash table for this - what's most appropriate. There are usually other constraints to consider as well like expected data size, available memory, expected mutability, quality of implementation, etc.

Comment: @Scheff'sCat Would you add your information as an answer? So I can mark it as solved?

Comment: *"I looked at some existing implementations of adjacency lists online, and most if not all of them have been implemented using dynamic arrays."* If you've searched for implementations of adjacency lists, then you're going to find implementations that use lists. That's just a matter of vocabulary. If you search for "adjacency matrix" you will find something very different, which might be considered a particular case of your suggested "adjacency hash tables": each vertex has an id between 0 and n-1; the hash function is the identity function; each hash-table is a size-n boolean vector.

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/146553/755

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The choice of the right container is not quite easy.

I will consider some of the most common:

- a list (elements which contain a reference to the next and/or previous)
- an array (with consecutive storage)
- an associated array
- a hash table.

Each of them has advantages and disadvantages.

Concerning a list, insertions and removals can be very fast (worst case O(1) if the insertion point / removal element is known) but a look-up has worst case time complexity of O(N).

The look-up in an array has a complexity of O(1) in worst case if the index is known (but insertion and removal can be slow if the order must be kept).

A hash table has a look-up of O(1) in best case but the worst case might be O(N) (even if it's unlikely to happen often if the hash table isn't completely bad implemented).

An associated array has a time complexity of O(lg N) in worst case.

So the choice always depends on the expected use cases to find the best compromise where the advantages pay off most while the disadvantages doesn't hurt too much.

For the management of node and edge lists in graphs, OP made the observation that arrays seem to be very common.

I recently had a look into the [Boost Graph Library](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_77_0/libs/graph/doc/) (for curiosity and inspiration). Concerning the data structures, it is mentioned:

> The `adjacency_list` class is the general purpose “swiss army knife” of graph classes. It is highly parameterized so that it can be optimized for different situations: the graph is directed or undirected, allow or disallow parallel edges, efficient access to just the out-edges or also to the in-edges, fast vertex insertion and removal at the cost of extra space overhead, etc.

For the configuration (according to a specific use case), there is spent an extra page [BGL – adjacency_list](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_77_0/libs/graph/doc/adjacency_list.html).

However, the defaults for vertex (node) list and edge list are in fact vectors (aka. dynamic arrays). Assuming that the average use case is an non-mutable graph (loaded once and never modified) which is explored by algorithms to answer certain user questions, the worst case of O(1) for look-up in arrays is hard to beat and will very probably pay off.

To organize this, the nodes and edges have to be enumerated. If the input data doesn't provide this, it's easy to add this as a kind of internal ID to the in-memory representation of the graph.

In this case, "public" node references have to be mapped into the internal IDs, and answers have to be mapped back. For the mapping of the public node references, the most appropriate container should be used. This might be in fact an associated array or hash table.

Considering that a request like e.g. find the shortest route from A to B has to map A and B once to the corresponding internal IDs but may need many look-up of nodes and edges to compute the answer, the choice of the array for storage of nodes and edges makes very sense.

Comment: In your original comment, you stated that the array was more cache friendly as opposed to a hash table. But why is this true considering that a hash table uses an array internally? It is true that calculating the hash value has an overhead. But is it not cache-friendly? Could you explain a bit more?

Comment: @OshanathRajawasam The key point is that the elements are _consecutively_ stored in an array. In a hash table, the elements will be spread into bins which are stored 
 somehow. (It depends on how the collision handling is done in the hash table.) Not sure how relevant this is when making random access to an array but it won't be worse compared to a hash table. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

> There are very limited scenarios where we would access graph nodes by index.

This is true, and exactly what you should be thinking about: you want a data structure which can efficiently do whatever operations you actually want to use it for. So the question is, what operations do you want to be efficient?

Suppose you are implementing some kind of standard algorithm which uses an adjacency list, e.g. Dijkstra's algorithm, A* search, depth-first search, breadth-first search, topological sorting, or so on. For almost every algorithm like this, you will find that the only operation you need to use the adjacency list for is: *for a given node, iterate over its neighbours*.

That operation is more efficient for a dynamic array than for a hashtable, because a hashtable has to be sufficiently sparse to prevent too many collisions. Besides that, dynamic arrays will use less memory than hashtables, for the same reason; and the dynamic arrays are more efficient to build in the first place, because you don't have to compute any hashes.

Now, if you have a different algorithm where you need to be able to test for the existence of an edge in O(1) time, then an adjacency list implemented using hashtables may be a good choice; but you should also consider whether an adjacency matrix is more suitable.

Comment: Nice explanation. I realized after you said, that, testing the existence of an edge incident on a particular node is not actually that useful in typical usage scenarios. I was convinced otherwise. Now I know better. Floyd-Warshall is the only situation where I think would require an adjacency matrix. Are there any other trivial uses for it?

Comment: @OshanathRajawasam There are certainly other algorithms which use adjacency matrices; the most interesting ones (to me) are those which treat it as an actual [matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_(mathematics)) in the mathematical sense, as you can do matrix multiplication with them and get meaningful results for example. The most straightforward example is that if `A` is an adjacency matrix with 0-1 entries, then `A^n` counts the number of different routes of length `n` between each pair of vertices.

Comment: Another practical situation where testing the existence of any given edge is very useful: when you make many updates (node and/or link additions and/or removals) to your graph. See https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/146325/fast-and-compact-data-structure-for-dynamic-graphs